# JDBC general query execution

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Is there a way, in JDBC, to execute a generic query ?
I mean run something like execute(String strSql) where strSql could be a SELECT, an INSERT, an UPDATE,a CREATE,... or whatever.

If no, how would you fix this up ?

Proposed solution:

```
@Override
public void execQuery(String Query) throws SQLException {
    this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
    if (this.statement.execute(Query)) {
        this.resultset = this.statement.getResultSet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh... Sorry guys, I've just found the solution by accident in one of my old sources, the following function solves this:

Comment: @Override
        public void execQuery(String Query) throws SQLException {

                        this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
                        if (this.statement.execute(Query)){
                                this.resultset = this.statement.getResultSet();
                        }
        }

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your proposed solution is susceptible a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Use [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead, as described in [*Using Prepared Statements*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Hi, trashgod, thanks for formatting my code ! Then, the app I'm developing executes user's SQL so SQL injection isn't a problem at all ;)

Comment: Btw, my app is targeted to developers, it allows running queries on a database that's why SQL inject. isn't an issue :)